# Examples of Maximal degeneration of Deligne on Calabi-Yau degeneration

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, hodge-theory, kahler-manifolds, calabi-yau, mirror-symmetry

Pierre Deligne in his celebrated paper entitling "[Local behavior of Hodge structures at infinity](https://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/71_Localbehavior.pdf)" introduced  [Maximal degenerations](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0011041.pdf) of Calabi-Yau manifolds.

Let $\pi:X\to \mathbb C^*$ be a family of degeneration of of Calabi-Yau fibers. We have from [D. Barlet](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01394271) asymptotic formula

$$\int_{X_s}\Omega_s\wedge\bar\Omega_s=C(\log |s|)^m|s|^{2k}(1+O(1))$$

for some $C \in \mathbb C^∗$, $k ∈ \mathbb Z, 0 \leq m \leq n = dim(X)$ and we can formulate $m$ via log-canonical threshold, see Proposition 2.1 of [this paper](https://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/christophe.mourougane/recherche/metric/CDG-terminal%202A.pdf) of Mourougane

In another view we want the degeneracy index $m=δ(X,X_0)$ defined by [Halle–Nicaise](https://arxiv.org/abs/1012.4969) be exactly $n=dim X$

We say that $X$ has [maximal degeneration](http://www.alt.mathematik.uni-mainz.de/Members/ruddat/calabi-yau-degenerations-and-related-geometries) at $s = 0$,  if in the
formula above we have $m = n$.

Later this definition become very important in Miror symmetry for example in Siebert-Gross program or Kontsevich-Soibelman program.

> I am woundring if there is any concrete example for maximal
>   degeneration on moduli space of Calabi-Yau fibers. Moreover, which properties are known that central fiber $X_0$ must have , to get such maximal degeneration ?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, I think there is a simple characterization in terms of the *Zariski* cohomology of $X_0$ due to Vadim Vologodsky: $H^n_{\rm Zar}(X_0, \mathbb{Q})\cong \mathbb{Q}$, see the first paragraph of his preprint "Geometric construction of the canonical coordinates" http://pages.uoregon.edu/vvologod/papers/gcin.pdf

Comment: OK, the definition of Deligne is slightly weaker than of this definition I mentioned. Moreover, I assumed Calabi-Yau manifold , Vadim Paper is on Calabi-Yau Scheme, which if we reduce his result over CY manifold we get nothing

Comment: there are many classical examples, like the Tate curve $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Z}\oplus\frac{1}{2\pi i}\log t\mathbb{Z}$, a Type III degeneration of K3 surfaces, or the family of quintic threefolds $z_0+\dots+z_4+tz_0\cdots z_4=0$

Comment: If central fiber be snc then the monodromy representation is unipotent, but inverse is not correct in general. and hence Kontsevitch-Soiblman definition of maximal degeneracy is different from Deligne. Your examples does not work for Kontsvitch-Soibleman maximal degeneracy.

Comment: If $ X $ is smooth and of dimension $ n + 1 $ and if you integrate a $\mathscr {C}^\infty $ form along the $ \pi$ fibers the power of the logarithm can not exceed $ n $ and it is unlikely maximal degeneracy led to GH limit and in fact GH limit is not depend to maximal degeneracy of asymptotic formula of integral of volumes on fibers.

Comment: Moreover, to have a non-zero term in $\vert s \vert^{2k.} (Log | s |)^n $ in the asymptotic formula of fiberwise integral of volume form the monodromy must have a block of Jordan of size $ n-1 $ for the eigenvalue 1 (on the cohomology of degree n of the Milnor fiber). This corresponds to a block of Jordan unipotent of maximum size.

Comment: Kontsevich-Soibelman program is unlikely to be correct for Gromov-Hausdorff limit of Calabi-Yau varieties

Comment: of course my examples work