# symplectic form on an algebraic family

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, fano-varieties

I know that smooth Fano varieties over $\mathbb{C}$ may be classified into a finite number of families in each dimension (1 in dimension 1, 10 in dimension 2, 105 in dimension 3 ...).

I am interested in cases where the Family is non-trivial (i.e. variety is not rigid).

Suppose that we have such a family, I assume that each of the members are anti-canonically polarized, hence each of the underlying varieties $X$ inherits a Kähler structure with Kähler form $\omega_{X}$, such that $[\omega_{X}] = c_{1}(TX)$.

I have two (probably very naïve) questions:

**Question 1**: Are the underlying Kähler forms $\omega_{X}$ abstractly symplectomorphic?

**Question 2**: Can/are these symplectic forms be induced from a symplectic form on (say the smooth locus of) the family?

Examples would also be appreciated.

Comment: You are facing with the two different notion of relative Kahler metrics introduced by Fujiki and others (Koiso and before him another person(I forgot his name a Japanese mathematician ))

Comment: Let $\pi:X \to S$ be a family of complex compact
manifolds. Then a (strong) relative K\"ahler form $\omega_{X/S}$ is
a relative $(1,1)$-form , which is given by $\omega_{X/S}|_{U_j}=\sqrt[]{-1}\partial_s\bar{\partial_s}u_j$
with respect to a suitable open covering $\{U_j\}$ of $X$. The
functions $u_j$ have to be strictly plurisubharmonic on
$U_j\cap X_s$, $s\in S$ and $u_j-u_k$ are harmonic on $U_j\cap U_k$.

Comment: A weak relative K\"ahler form is given in a similar way, where the
$u_j-u_k$ need only be harmonic on the fibers $X_s\cap U_j\cap U_k$ ( $\partial_s$
and $\bar{\partial_s}$ denote derivatives in fiber direction)

Comment: As remark, fiberwise Ricci flat metric and in general fiberwise Kahler-Einstein metrics  are strong relative K\"ahler form. In fact any fiberwise K\"ahler-Einstein metric can be introduced locally by this definition.

Comment: But $\omega_{X/Y}$ on $\pi:X\to Y$ may no longer be closed and we need to finite mass to get closedness (due to being  non-smooth) . But the induced of fibers are K\"ahler due to  Kodaira-Spencer map

Comment: Note that such fiberwise Kahler metric is not in $c_1(TX)$, it is in $c_1(K_{X/Y})$. i.e. relative first Chern class $c_1(K_{X/Y})=-dd^c\log \Omega_{X/Y}$ where $\Omega_{X/Y}$ is relative volume form

Comment: Closedness of $(1,1)$− current when you extend from fibers to whole of total space in singular setting is more complicated see Theorem 1.26, of https://thichthichiu.files.wordpress.com/2011/07/guedj-v-cours-m2r-2011-2012.pdf .

Comment: references: Schumacher, Georg: Moduli of polarized K¨ahler manifolds, Math. Ann. 269, 137–144 (1984).  and Fujiki, Akira; Schumacher, Georg: The moduli space of extremal compact K¨ahler manifolds and generalized
Weil-Petersson metrics. Publ. Res. Inst. Math. Sci. 26, 101–183 (1990).

Comment: positivity of such fiberwise Kahler-Einstein metric is highly non-trivial. It is still open question. When fibers are of general type there is a paper of Schumacher,in Invent math(with two erratam ) but at the moment I couldn't yet accept his proof. So such forms are not Kahler in general . In my point of view  Kontsevich-Soibelman program (which they have copy pasted from Barlet formula(in Invent Math) and Grifiths)is equivalent with positivity of such semi ricci flat forms . See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/261281/examples-of-maximal-degeneration-of-deligne-on-calabi-yau-degeneration

Comment: My letter to Gang Tian can give more effectiveness of it https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01551080/document

Comment: @HassanJolany In general, if you feel like writing a long sequence of comments, you should consider writing an answer instead.  In fact, it might be better to write an answer to this question, and delete these comments.

Comment: For the relative forms, we have a new notion of positivity introduced by Daniel Barlet. Let me explain it here and state my conjecture.Let $π: X → S$ be a surjective holomorphic map between two irreducible complex spaces. Let $ p : Gr_q(X/S) → X$ be the Grassmannian of $q$−planes in $T_{X/S}$, $U$ the universal
$q$−vector bundle on $Gr_q(X/S)$, and $θ : Λ^q(U) → Gr_q(X/S)$ the line bundle which is
the determinant of $U$. A $π$−relative continuous$ (q, q)$−form on $X $ defines a continuous
hermitian form on $Λ^q(U).$

Comment: .....We shall say that a $π$−relative continuous $(q, q)$−form $ω$ on $X$ is
strongly Lelong positive at $x_0$ if the hermitian form on $Λ^q(U)$ defined by$ ω$ is a positive hermitian form at each point of $p^{-1}(x_0)$ . For any $q$−plane $P$ in the Zariski tangent space $T_{X,x_0}$
which is vertical (i.e. contained in the kernel of $T_{π,x_0}$
) then $ω_{x_0}[v_1 ∧ · · · ∧ v_q] > 0$
when $v_1, . . . , v_q$ is a basis of $P$

Comment: My conjecture is that on degeneration of Calabi-Yau fibers , the relative form (semi-flat form introduced by Vafa-Yau ) is semi-positive in the sense of Daniel Barlet, i.e it is strongly Lelong positive. see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.01743.pdf

Comment: End of comment: A degeneration$X\to \Delta$ give you a family of fibers $X_t$  parametrized by the base $\Delta$. Also in some books, family $(X_t,L_t)$ are defined by restricting on $X\times \{t\}$ where $t\in \Delta$ . In my all comments, I have assumed you mean a family via degeneration parametrized by the base which is curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(X_\alpha, \mathcal{L}_\alpha)_{\alpha\in A}=(M, L, J_\alpha, \overline{\partial}_\alpha)_{\alpha\in A}$ be a family of polarized varieties, with $A$ the complex manifold parametrizing the family (assumed to be connected).  Here is $M$ the common underlying smooth manifold of the varieties $X_\alpha$, $J_\alpha$ are the integrable almost-complex structures corresponding to the different varieties $X_\alpha$, $L$ is the common underlying smooth complex line bundle of the $J_\alpha$-holomorphic line bundles $\mathcal{L}_\alpha$, and $\overline{\partial}_{\alpha}$ are the integrable delbar-operators on $L$ corresponding to the different holomorphic line bundles $\mathcal{L}_\alpha$.

**Lemma:** For each $\alpha_0\in A$, there is a neighbourhood $U\subseteq A$ of $\alpha_0$, and a smoothly varying family $(\omega_\alpha)_{\alpha\in U}$ of symplectic forms in $c_1(L)$, such that for each $\alpha$, the form $\omega_\alpha$ is $J_\alpha$-Kähler.

*Sketch proof:*  For each $\alpha$ we have a map
$$F_\alpha: \{\text{hermitian metrics on $L$}\}\to \{\text{real 2-forms in $c_1(L)$}\}$$ given by sending a hermitian metric on $L$ to $-i$ times the curvature of its $(J_\alpha,\overline{\partial}_\alpha)$-Chern connection.  The maps $F_\alpha$ vary smoothly with $\alpha$.  If $\omega_0$ is a $J_{\alpha_0}$-Kähler form, there is some hermitian metric $h$ on $L$ such that $F_{\alpha_0}(h)=\omega_0$.  For $\alpha$ sufficiently close to $\alpha_0$, the $J_\alpha-(1,1)$-form $\omega_\alpha:=F_\alpha(h)$ is also nondegenerate, and so is $J_\alpha$-Kähler. $\square$

It follows that the space of 2-forms in $c_1(L)\in H^2(M,\mathbb{Z})$ which are Kähler for some $J_\alpha$ is connected.  By the Moser trick, all these 2-forms are isotopic to each other.  This answers your **first question**.

It also follows that one can smoothly select elements $(\omega_\alpha)_{\alpha\in a}$ of $c_1(L)\in H^2(M,\mathbb{Z})$, which are respectively $J_\alpha$-Kähler.

**Edit:** For the second question, I had previously proposed the pullback $\pi_1^*\omega_\alpha+\pi_2^*\widetilde\omega$ as a potential symplectic form on $M\times A$, where $\widetilde\omega$ is some symplectic form on $A$.  But, now that I think about it, this pullback is not necessarily closed.

On the other hand, by the arguments for the first question, we can select smoothly varying diffeomorphisms $\psi:A\to\operatorname{Diff}(M)$ such that for all $\alpha$, $\psi_\alpha^*\omega_\alpha=\omega_{\alpha_0}$.  (Maybe this requires simple connectedness of $A$?)  Write $\Psi:M\times A\to M\times A$ for the induced diffeomorphism $\Psi(x,\alpha)=(\psi_\alpha(x),\alpha)$.  Then $(\Psi^{-1})^*(\pi_1^*\omega_{\alpha_0}+\pi_2^*\widetilde\omega)$ is a symplectic form which restricts on $\alpha$-slices to $\omega_\alpha$, which should answer the **second question**.

I had also mentioned some general references on moduli spaces of Fano varieties (because of the issue of finding a symplectic form $\widetilde\omega$ on $A$), which I will preserve: [1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.0761), [2](https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.0858).

Comment: I have deleted some comments that push the boundaries of professionalism.

Comment: My comments must comeback! (they are very important!)(I stop to work on MO from now until my comments appear)

Comment: Let $φ : X → B$ be a family of complex manifolds, $0 ∈ B$. If the
central fibre $X_0$ is Kahler, then so is $X_b$ for all $b$ sufficiently near $0.$, For proof see Theorem 9.23 of the book of (Claire Voisin Hodge Theory due to Kodaira)http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~dnovikov/Manifolds5775/Claire_Voisin_Hodge_Theory_and_CAG.pdf

Comment: Moreover, In symplectic geometry we have two notions of Inflation and Deflation which developed by McDuff and V.Shevchishin see Theorem 0.3, and Theorem of 0.4 https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.01518.pdf , Let $J$ be an $ω_0-$ tamed almost complex structure on a symplectic 4-manifold $(X,ω_0)$ that admits an embedded $J$-holomorphic curve $C$ with $[C]·[C]>0$. Then there is a family $ω_s$, for $s≥0$, of symplectic forms that all tame $J$ and have cohomology class $$[ω_s] = [ω_0] +sPD([C]),$$ where $PD([C])$ is Poincare dual to $[C]$

Comment: @macbeth : Anyway, I don't think your "Sketch proof" is fine, you may look into the theorem of **Kodaira** I mentioned in my previous comment and edit your proof.

Comment: More comment: If central fibre $X_0$ be Kahler on $π:X→Δ $, then from Kodaira theorem the fibers $X_s$ when $s→0$ are Kahler also, but Kodaira didn't claim that when such $X_s$ could be projective. There are some theorems related it developed by Junyan Cao in his Ph.D. thesis. For instance, if central fiber be compact Kahler Calai-Yau manifold, or tangent bundle $T_{X_0}$ be "nef", or the hermitian metric of $−K_{X_0}$ be semi-positive then $X_s$ are projective when $s→0$(as a sequence) see https://hal.inria.fr/file/index/docid/749923/filename/Def_pub.pdf

Comment: In final let me mention the ${\text{Demailly-Paun conjecture}}$ for the global stability of Kahler structures: Let $X \to S$ be a deformation of compact complex manifolds over an irreducible base $S$. Assume that one of the fibers $X_{t_0}$ is Kahler. Then there exists a countable union $ S'\subset S$ ( $S$ of analytic subsets in the base such that $X_t $ is Kahler for $t ∈ S \setminus S'$ . Moreover, $S$ can be chosen so that the Kahler cone is invariant
over $S \setminus S′$ , under parallel transport by the Gauss-Manin connection. http://annals.math.princeton.edu/2004/159-3/p05